# Can I repost samsung kernel sources on my repo?

Tags: kernel, source, licenses, gpl

Samsung sources for Android are available at https://opensource.samsung.com but it's painful to download programatically. I believe that I'm free to do whatever I want with their kernel code including publishing it anywhere. Am I right?

Comment: What does the license say you are allowed to do with it?  US copyright law, at least, states that any right not expressly granted, is forbidden.

Comment: I'm in no way a lawyer. I would encourage you to read https://opensource.samsung.com/terms and then would be careful, on the publication, when writing the name of the brand and / or tryng to make money with the publication. (advertising included)

Comment: I downloaded one of the kernel archives to read the license.  Most are the kernel's license, which is GPL2.  A few of the files with Samsung's copyright notice say GPL2 or later.  At least one has no notice in it at all.

Comment: GPL2 absolutely allows that.

Comment: I thought the answer would be whatever is in the kernel license, that I should be able to modify and republish. I think I should just not use the samsung name and instead the phone codename or model/code

Comment: How is it difficult to download? What is so difficult about `git clone`/`git pull`?

Comment: @Bib https://opensource.samsung.com/ this is not a git repo and there's no URL for downloading